# I cannot use ntfs partitions from Ubuntu, how can I fix?

Tags: mount, ntfs, partitioning

I have windows 10 and ubuntu-16.04 installed in dual boot.

I want to get into the Linux universe from time to time and I have a problem that is rather intriguing to me! When I  installed, Ubuntu already has Windows 10 installed with two C: and D: partitions.

To install Ubuntu I created a third partition with on the hard disk and installed ubuntu in dual boot! Until then, everything OK !!

When I opened the Ubuntu OS I can see the disks C: and D: and I can read and write files on them !! But after using the system two or three times, do not know the right, is no longer allowed to read or write the disks through Ubuntu!

What happened?

Comment: What error(s) are given?. I speculate [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/145902/178596) may be your issue, or it is has been corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, its probably because Ubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

## in Windows...

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f d:`
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: Who down-voted me, and why? Inquiring minds want to know.

Comment: Wasn't me, but I *could* imagine it is because a 5.5 k user probably knows the essence of this answer by heart, since it was posted tons of times.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks for your response! Please explain further, as I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: ^ If I search for "unclean" on AU, I get no less then 280(!) posts, of which most are posted on exactly the same cause as this question. Anyone who has been longer on the site than a week must have seen several on them, because it has been asked over and over again. Then answering the question instead of linking to one of the many dupes is a bit faint imo. No offense btw.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks again for your repsonse! And thanks for the clarification. I'll get better at citing links.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Gentlemen, do you think that the fact that there are 280(!) posts related to unclean indicates that we are collectively failing in our [merge requests?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16361/what-criteria-should-be-used-when-considering-merge-candidates). That's a lot of posts.

Comment: @ElderGeek Yeah, there are many. Not all 280 will be perfect matches, but still. Many of them have accepted answers, which makes many people loose (a little) rep when merged.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Perhaps a canonical answer with those that fit the mold flagged as dupes is a better approach then? I'm still unclear as to the criteria for [merge requests.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16361/what-criteria-should-be-used-when-considering-merge-candidates) Clearly I'm not the only one who would like to know and my answer appears to be insufficient. I'd love to have some feedback there.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I've been thinking about this. It's obvious that most new users aren't searching for posts that are similar enough to answer their question. Now of the 280 hits that you saw, it's suggested that **I** look through them to find one that answers the question, and then cite a link... instead of just answering the question for the millionith time? I've got better things to do with my time than doing the OP's work for them. I can answer the question in seconds, whilst searching/reading/citing could take me minutes or hours. So what if the answer is repeated a bunch of times?

Comment: @ElderGeek thoughts about my last comment?

Comment: @heynnema Hi!  If you are going to post the same answer across multiple questions, first check if the question here and the question you originally answered are similar enough to be duplicates.  If they are, consider flagging or close voting the question as a duplicate instead of copying your answer across multiple questions.

Comment: @ElderGeek merges are only useful when duplicate questions have different, useful answers edit: I better go look at your question

Comment: @ThomasWard please read my last comment to JacobVlijm. Thanks. I'm not sure that it's my responsibility to search the database for similar answers, for the OP. It's faster for me to just answer the question.

Comment: Hello, I know you want to help people but the better way would not involve duplicating answers. Consider voting to close the question as a duplicate. It may take a little more time but it will be more beneficial in the long run.

Comment: @heynnema Actually, [it IS our collective responsibilty to locate and flag duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243343/260418) That being said, this is likely better discussed on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/)